# How to traverse over reversed queryset in django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to traverse twice over one reversed object, initally the for loop works but not on the second loop.

```
x = Subscription.objects.filter(customer_id=customer_id).order_by('-id')[:count]
tmp = reversed(x)
y = call_function(subs=tmp) # inside this function as well object is of type reversed and i am able to loop over it inside the call_function.

for j in tmp: # this loop is not running at all. here as well tmp is a reversed object
    print(j)
```

```
# call_function(subs=s)
def call_function(s):
    for i in s:
       print(i)
```

Comment: `reversed` is an iterator, so the second time you loop, the iterator is already "exhausted".

Answer (score 1):

[**`reversed(…)`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) is an *iterator*, not an *iterable*, so the second time you loop, the iterator is already "exhausted". It is thus just a "shallow object", that "walks" through the `QuerySet` in reversed order.

You thus use `reversed(…)` *twice*. This will *not* make the query a second time, since the `QuerySet` will cache the result, so:

```
x = Subscription.objects.filter(customer_id=customer_id).order_by('-id')[:count]
tmp = reversed(x)
y = call_function(subs=tmp)

for j in reversed(x):
    print(j)
```

Comment: I tried this and we can not ```reversed()``` the same object twice

Comment: @Kapil: why not?

Comment: ```TypeError: 'reversed' object is not reversible```

Comment: @Kapil: sorry, it is `reversed(x)`, not `reversed(tmp)`.